# How to render a function return to HTML (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand how Typescript and HTML are passing data.

(Typescript)

```
  public getContactByTradingPartnerId(tradingPartnerId: number):string {
    const map = {
        1001 : "test1@gmail.com",
        2 : "test2@gmail.com",
        11 : "test@gmail.com"
    }
    return map[tradingPartnerId] ?? "A contact has not been found for this trading partner."
```

(HTML)

```
<div class="example-element-description">
    {{element.tradingPartnerId}}
</div>
```

How can I pass the element.tradingpartnerid to the typescript function getContactByTradingPartnerId so that it renders the contact? (Example. the element.tradingPartnerId is 1001 so it renders test1@gmail.com on the UI).

Comment: from where is your ```element``` comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the typescript method within the {{}} (assuming the html view is linked to an angular component containing your function).

```
<div class="example-element-description">
    {{getContactByTradingPartnerId(element.tradingPartnerId)}}
</div>
```

Usually you'll want to avoid calling functions in the templating accolades.

Comment: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1):

You can set inner HTML values of element in angular like:
`[innerHtml]="value"`

So you can try:

```
<div class="example-element-description" 
    [innerHtml]="getContactByTradingPartnerId(element.tradingPartnerId)">
</div>
```